# ButterKnife error: cannot find symbol method findRequiredViewAsType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

I'm using ButterKnife for along time.
But I have error which see for first time and didnt find solution for this.

ERROR:

```
Error:(24, 36) error: cannot find symbol method findRequiredViewAsType(Object,int,String,Class<ImageView>)
```

I tried bindView like always

> @BindView(R.id.menu_hamburgerIcon) ImageView menuHamburger;

Also added in gradle:

```
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
```

But still getting this error in genereted class by ButterKnife.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have:

```
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
```

but

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
```

The trick here is that you must use the same version in both entries and you got `8.0.1` and `8.1.0` (most likely C&P or typo), Just set `compile` to `8.1.0` too and you should be good:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
```